# Statement, Expression, ExpressionStatements. Отличие и корректный перевод

Tags: javascript, expressions

Столкнулся с понятиями Statement, Expression, ExpressionStatements в книге [Douglas Crockford. JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do).

Например, [Esprima](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html#) парсер не выделяет Statement, если я правильно понял, корректно его перевести как "директива, инструкция", но использует ExpressionStatement.

Укажите, пожалуйста, как они соотносятся между собой и как их корректно перевести?

Comment: добавь контекст в котором эти понятия вводятся в книге

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если обратиться к [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/), можно найти определение данных понятий:

1. [*Statement*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-Statement) - общее название всех основных выражений, как можно увидеть, выражения бывают нескольких видов

   ```
   Statement[Yield, Return]:
       BlockStatement[?Yield, ?Return]
       VariableStatement[?Yield]
       EmptyStatement
       ExpressionStatement[?Yield]
       IfStatement[?Yield, ?Return]
       BreakableStatement[?Yield, ?Return]
       ContinueStatement[?Yield]
       BreakStatement[?Yield]
       [+Return]ReturnStatement[?Yield]
       WithStatement[?Yield, ?Return]
       LabelledStatement[?Yield, ?Return]
       ThrowStatement[?Yield]
       TryStatement[?Yield, ?Return]
       DebuggerStatement
   ```

   Как можно заметить [*ExpressionStatement*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-ExpressionStatement) просто один из видов *Statement*, вполне возможно именно поэтому указанный парсер не выделяет *Statement* отдельно.
2. В свою очередь [*ExpressionStatement*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-ExpressionStatement) представляет из себя *Expression*, перед которым нет **{**, **function**, **class**, **let [**

   ```
   ExpressionStatement[Yield]:
       [lookahead ∉ { {, function, class, let [ }]Expression[In, ?Yield];
   ```
3. И, наконец, [*Expression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-Expression) - почти любое выражение, которое можно вычислить и получить значение. Определяется оно, как один или несколько [*AssignmentExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-AssignmentExpression), разделенных запятыми. Которые в свою очередь могут быть: тернарным оператором, стрелочной функцией, yield выражением, либо выражением с применением операторов присваивания.

---

С переводом, все несколько сложнее. На сколько я знаю, общеупотребимого перевода нет. В википедии присутствует вариант [*Инстру́кция или опера́тор*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). Кроме этого есть [обсуждение на соседнем сайте](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/7583/8208)

Comment: спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ! можно понимать выражение как кусок кода, который возвращает объект здесь и сейчас. а statement - как выражение, которое еще и взаимодействует с средой запуска (присваивает переменную, сравнивает объекты и тп)?

Comment: @while1pass, нет, по сути выражение _и есть_ statement, но не любой _statement_ - выражение :-) Например: _EmptyStatement_ - никак не взаимодействует со средой. Опять же, присваивание вполне входит в _AssignmentExpression_. И в принципе возвращает значение.